# Test for monitor resolutions

Tags: xorg, monitors, intel, display

I want to buy a new display device, but I don't know if it will be supported by my card because the weirder/higher resolutions: 2560 x 1080, or 2560 x 1440.

Is there any method to create a virtual display with that resolutions to prove that is actually possible to get that resolutions with this card?

Of course, a testing method that works for any graphics card is welcomed. But for instance, the graphics card is an Intel from a i5-M520 processor.

Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You can see what resolutions are available with the command `xrandr`.

Comment: Check [Intel](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-022544.htm)'s answer to *Can I get a list of resolutions that my Intel graphics support ?*  Unless your OEM limited the available resolutions, your iGPU should support all video modes the display EDID claims to support (up to a maximum of 2560 x 1600). _P.S._ As far as I know `xrandr` only reports supported resolutions for connected displays (i.e. `LVDS1`) not for a fictive display.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your X server's configuration - see `DISPLAY SUBSECTION` in the `xorg.conf` man page, especially the `Virtual` option. Since X11 often comes without non-empty configuration (either in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*`) these days, you may need to use `X -configure` to generate one to start with.